# Help with LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

If I was just wanting the earliest [event] [startTime] I'd write:

```
events.Min(ev => ev.StartTime);
```

How can I extend this to say:

```
"select the [startTime] for the [event] that has the earliest [appointment] [startTime]"
```

(An [event] has an Appointments collection of [appointment])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by min appointment start time and take the first, something like:

```
events.OrderBy(ev => ev.Appointments.Min(app => app.StartTime)).First().StartTime;
```